# How to add Google places autocomplete to flask?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, autocomplete

I would like to add the Google places autocomplete library to an input field but am not able to in my flask app (it doesn't give the dropdown suggestions), although it works fine in a standalone HTML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you consider using [Geocomplete](https://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/)? The example code they provide is pretty easy to implement

Comment: Thanks , will surely look at it and come back.

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: Hey @IamMashed, used the geocomplete plugin as suggested and it worked pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

If you managed to implement the search box itself in your flask app (it's being rendered and everything) but there are no drop-down suggestions you should be able to find out the exact error message in the developer tools of your browser.

One of the reasons could be that the URL of your web app is not included in your API key to accept requests from.

Comment: I used the Geocomplete plugin above and it seemed to work pretty well. Thanks for your suggestion though, it could be used by anyone else who ever faces this.